# cstdlib compilation namespace error

Tags: c++, std, visibility

I'm cross compiling cpp files from Windows 8 64-bit machine to ARM-Cortex M. Everything works but when I need stdlib it gives me the following errors :

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.8 2014q2\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.4/cstdlib:114:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
 namespace std _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
 ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.8 2014q2\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.4/cstdlib:115:1: error: expected ',' or ';' before '{' token
 {
 ^
In file included from C:/mbed/mbed-src/api/platform.h:27:0,
                 from C:/mbed/mbed-src/api/mbed.h:21,
                 from test.cpp:1:
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.8 2014q2\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.4/cstdio:94:1: error: unknown type name 'namespace'
 namespace std
 ^
C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.8 2014q2\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.4/cstdio:95:1: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' be
fore '{' token
 {
 ^
```

I googled this and I think that visisbility might be causing problems on Windows but I don't know how to fix it. I followed the sources and I found that :

```
# define _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY 1

#if _GLIBCXX_HAVE_ATTRIBUTE_VISIBILITY
# define _GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(V) __attribute__ ((__visibility__ (#V)))
#else
```

I found that in c++config.h file. My complete g++ command is :

```
arm-none-eabi-g++ -v -Os -flto -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-builtin -Wall -Wextra -pipe -fvisibility=hidden -x c -Os -mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfloat
-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -fno-inline -DSTM32F401xC  -DSTM32F401xx -DNDEBUG -DTOOLCHAIN_GCC_CW=1 -IC:/mbed/mbed-src/api -IC:/mbed/mbed-src/hal -IC:/mbed/mbed-
src/targets/hal/TARGET_STM/TARGET_USTM32 -IC:/mbed/mbed-src/targets/cmsis  -IC:/mbed/mbed-src/targets/cmsis/TARGET_STM/TARGET_USTM32 -IC:/mbed/mbed-libs/MicroLC
D -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.8 2014q2\arm-none-eabi\include\c++\4.8.4" -I"C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU Tools ARM Embedded\4.8 2014q2\arm-n
one-eabi\include\c++\4.8.4\arm-none-eabi" -c test.cpp -o test.o
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you compile your code as "C" code instead of "C++" code with this compiler flag:

```
-x c
```

That means of course that "namespace" is not a valid keyword, as it only exists in C++.

Try changing it to

```
-x c++
```

or, even better, just remove it. Gcc usually figures this out from the file ending (.cpp vs .c)

Comment: this works... I just removed the flag... Thank you for noticing my mistake :D

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you are missing some `-std=c++11` or `-std=c++03` flag to your `arm-none-eabi-g++` ; are you able to compile your code on a Linux desktop?